# If f is a function such that f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b) for all real numbers a and b, then justify the statement f(-a) = -f(a).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been unable to reach a solution with the assumption b = -2a and various others, and ChatGTP's answer where a=-a and b=a has a mistake in one of its steps as far as I can tell.

If you can answer using high school algebra and show each step, it would help a lot.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Hint:  start by showing that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You shouldn't do math using ChatGPT. Although suprisingly it did seem to have the right idea here.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question like this on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $a=0=b$:

$$f(0) = f(0) + f(0)\Longrightarrow f(0)=0.$$

Now substitute $b=-a$:

$$0=f(0)=f(a-a)=f(a)+f(-a) \Longrightarrow f(-a)=-f(a).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is my first time tackling proof questions like this rather than the usual numerical questions and I have a further question on your solution if you the time: should the second assumption (b=-a) always be consistent with the first assumption (a=0=b) in solutions like this?

Comment: If I get what you mean: No, since your functional equation works for all real numbers, you can substitute whatever you want and still get something that has to be right. Everything you find through such substitutions, you can use everywhere else. For example here you find in the first line that if $f$ exists, then $f(0)=0$ has to be true. In the second line you then use this fact to find what you wanted to find.

Comment: If you want a good pdf to learn about functional equations: [here](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) is one.